# Triangle nequality with $\prod_{cyc}\left(2\sin^2{A}+\frac{1}{\sin^2{A}}\right)$

Tags: inequality

In $\Delta ABC$,show that
$$\left(2\sin^2{A}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{A}}\right)\left(2\sin^2{B}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{B}}\right)\left(2\sin^2{C}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{C}}\right)\ge \left(\dfrac{17}{6}\right)^3$$

This inequality can't use Jenson inequality such consider 
$$f(x)=\ln{\left(2\sin^2{x}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{x}}\right)}$$,Indeed,$f''(x)$ can change this sign,so I'm stuck there. Any help please?

Comment: Use $A+B+C=\pi$ to write $\sin C$ in terms of $\sin A$ and $\sin B$. Then let $x=\sin A$ and $y=\sin B$. Basically, $\sin^2x$ is a positive quantity in between $0$ and $1$, while $\dfrac1{\sin^2x}$ is also positive, but on $(1,\infty)$. Trigonometry won't matter at this point anymore.

Comment: use the $AM-GM$ inequality

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a concise way to prove it. But $\color{red}{Lagrange\ Multiplier}$ can use to solve it.
Let $$f(A,B,C)=\left(2\sin^2{A}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{A}}\right)\left(2\sin^2{B}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{B}}\right)\left(2\sin^2{C}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2{C}}\right)$$
You know that $$A+B+C=\pi$$

Now using Lagrange Multiplier:
Let $$F(A,B,C,\lambda)=f(A,B,C)+\lambda(A+B+C-\pi)$$
Solve the following equation:
\begin{cases}
F'_A=0\\
F'_B=0\\
F'_C=0\\
F'_\lambda=0\\
\end{cases}
It's trivial that $A=B=C=\frac\pi3$. And there is only solution for $A$,$B$ and $C$, so $$f_{min}(A,B,C)=f(\frac\pi3,\frac\pi3,\frac\pi3)=(\frac{17}{6})^3$$